# Return type from string literal type parameter

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

```js
function assertNever(x: never): never {
  throw new Error('Should never occur.')
}

type StudentMessage =
  | 'get-grades'
  | 'get-best-grade'
  | 'add-grade'

type MessageFunction<TMessage extends StudentMessage> =
  TMessage extends 'get-grades'
  ? () => number[]
  : TMessage extends 'get-best-grade'
  ? () => number
  : TMessage extends 'add-grade'
  ? (grade: number) => void
  : never

function Student(grades: number[]){
  const _grades = [...grades];

  return function<TMessage extends StudentMessage>(message: TMessage): MessageFunction<TMessage> {
    switch(message){
      case 'get-grades':
        return () => _grades;

      case 'get-best-grade':
        return () => Math.min(..._grades);

      case 'add-grade':
        return (grade: number) => {_grades.push(grade)};

      default:
        assertNever(message)
    }
  }
}
```

I'm getting the following errors:

```bash
Type '() => number[]' is not assignable to type 'MessageFunction<TMessage>'.
Type '() => number' is not assignable to type 'MessageFunction<TMessage>'.
Type '(grade: number) => void' is not assignable to type 'MessageFunction<TMessage>'.
```

I don't understand, why TypeScript does infer the correct types but still throws an Error at the return statements inside the switch statement.

Comment: If `TMessage` is `"get-grades" | "add-grade"`, you should be returning a union of functions, but clearly, you aren't. There is a feature request for a type parameter annotation `oneof` to say that `TMessage` is not a union ([ms/TS#27808](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27808)), though. You could get around it with an overload like Dimava has shown below

Answer (score 0):

The function signature

```
function<TMessage extends StudentMessage>(message: TMessage): MessageFunction<StudentMessage>
```

does conform to what you want and is what's going on in building the result.  The return cases from your `switch` are all coming from the specific type `StudentMessage` from the `case` and in a sense you've "removed" the `TMessage`ness.

Comment: Already tried this, but it aggregates the resulting function signatures into one.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use generic overload for such case

```
function assertNever(x: never): never {
    throw new Error('Should never occur.')
}

type StudentMessage =
    | 'get-grades'
    | 'get-best-grade'
    | 'add-grade'

type MessageFunctionMap = {
    'get-grades': () => number[]
    'get-best-grade': () => number
    'add-grade': (grade: number) => void
}

function Student(grades: number[]) {
    const _grades = [...grades];

    return f;
    function f<TMessage extends StudentMessage>(message: TMessage): MessageFunctionMap[TMessage];
    function f(message: StudentMessage): MessageFunctionMap[StudentMessage] {
        switch (message) {
            case 'get-grades':
                return () => _grades;

            case 'get-best-grade':
                return () => Math.min(..._grades);

            case 'add-grade':
                return (grade: number) => { _grades.push(grade) };

            default:
                assertNever(message)
        }
    }
}
```